# Eclipse plugin: Get events when an editor is opened or closed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

Can anyone tell which of the methods are called whenever an editor is opened and closed. I want to process an event whenever these methods are called.

Thanks
Ishan

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IPartListener` to listen for changes to the state of all parts. This will tell you about editors (and views) being opened and closed.

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.addPartListener(partListener);
```

The listener `partActivated` and `partClosed` methods will tell you about parts opening and closing. The `IWorkbenchPart` argument of these methods will be an instance of `IEditorPart` for an editor.

Comment: Where I should put these lines. I used the same and kept it in init() method of an editor. But it is called whenever the same editor is opened with different file. and the derived methods are called for any editor of any file.

Comment: This will give you events for every part. You will have to look at the parameters to the methods and filter out the parts you want.